# Cделать выборку строк из масива по указанному значению

Tags: c#

Исходный код:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match m in matches)
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups[1].Value))
        sb.AppendLine(domen + m.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
    File.AppendAllText("Out.txt" , sb.ToString());
```

Как загнать все строки из переменной `sb` в массив и сделать выборку по указанному значению (например только строки с `php`) и так же обрезать строки с указанным разделителем?

пробовал таким макаром:

```
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match m in matches)
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups[1].Value))
            sb.AppendLine(domen + m.Groups[1].Value.Trim());

    string[] fined = sb;

    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

    foreach (string str5 in fined)
        {
        list2.Add(str5);

        string[] strArray3 = list2.Split(new char[] { '&' });
        string str33 = strArray3[0];
```

не выходит, подскажите варианты пожалуйста, как лучше решить эти задачи по проще может есть варианты еще какие?

Comment: не экономьте на фигурных скобках :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужны строки в виде массива - не склеивайте их в одну большую строку:

```
string [] matchedLines = matches.Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(m => m.m.Groups[1].Value)
                          .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
                          .Select(l => l.Trim())
                          .ToArray();
```

Из остатка кода вообще тяжело понять что там происходит. Но раз у вас коллекция строк, то работайте с ней как с коллекцией. Например, выбирайте строки с PHP вот так:

```
var linesWithPHP = matchedLines.Where(l => l.Contains("PHP"));
```

или как-то вроде

```
string[] linesWithPHP = matchedLines.Where(l => l.Contains("PHP")).ToArray();
```

Comment: спасибо, еще какие варианты можете предложить?

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример на основе моего кода выше ато не понятно не чего, с вашим вариантом чет не получается у меня...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta это и есть пример на основе вашего кода, который получает сверху matches (результат вызова Regex?) и выдает на выходе массив строк со словом PHP в них (может только стоит заменить Contains на [IndexOf c указанием StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx), чтобы `"php"` тоже находило). пройдитесь по шагам и выясните что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: у меня там линки вида: http://domen.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=212&feedback=239
http://domen.com/index.php?id=10&showauthornr=206755
http://domen.com/deu/index2010.php?nav=0&sub1=0&sub2=&menu_id=302&va=leben_und_tod вашим вариантом попробовал выводят только домены обрезанные почему то и слишними символами... тоесть хвоста/URI обрезаются...

Comment: у меня там линки вида: http://domen.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=212&feedback=239
http://domen.com/index.php?id=10&showauthornr=206755
http://domen.com/deu/index2010.php?nav=0&sub1=0&sub2=&menu_id=302&va=leben_und_tod вашим вариантом попробовал выводят только домены обрезанные почему то и слишними символами...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta из вашего вопроса не видно ни оригинального текста, ни выражения, которым вы выбираете ссылки. код ответе никак не меняет строки (по сравнению с вашим кодом) вы спросили как достать строчки из sb и отфильтровать те, в которых есть PHP - я именно это и написал вам - не складывать строки в sb, оставлять их в виде массива. и фильтровать вызовом Where. Что у вам там приходит в matches, что обрезается, а что нет - это из вашего вопроса непонятно. совсем.

Comment: К примеру линк: http://domen.com/index.php?id=10&showauthornr=206755 , тут нужно обрезать строку до символа "&" то есть этот кусок: http://domen.com/index.php?id=10

Comment: @GeneratorSveta ну допишите после Where еще один Select, в котором обрежте строку. Или задайте новый вопрос (с кодом, который можно будет запустить и исправить)

Comment: понял ок спасибо...